# Get the name of product from EcoResProduct or InventTable Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Does anyone know how to get the name of a product from EcoResProduct on Dynamics ax on a Job?

I found some things like I have to use the EcoResProductTraslation, but I cant find the relation or something to get the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `InventTable.productName()` might be useful for your purpose. The method finds a product variant that is based on the value of the `_inventDimId` parameter. If the product variant is found then its name is returned; otherwise, the name of a product that this item represents is returned.
Please check the example below:

```
InventTable           inventTable;
EcoResProduct         ecoResProduct;
EcoResProductName     productName;
;

inventTable = InventTable::find('AnyItemId');          
productName = inventTable.productName(SystemParameters::getSystemLanguageId());

info(productName);

ecoResProduct = EcoResProduct::find(inventTable.Product);         
productName   = ecoResProduct.productName();

info(productName);
```

You can investigate the code of function to understand what it actually does. Also you can use cross references to find examples where it is used.

Comment: could yo give me an example ? I'm really new on Dynamics and is a litle bit complicate for my understand how it works that but thank you for your time !!

Comment: Thanks, but this code do not show variant of product. for show variants can use this : inventTable.productName(CompanyInfo::languageId(),inventDim.inventDimId);

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is indeed a bit tricky, but thankfully AX standard already has a display method that does the heavy lifting for you: `EcoResProduct.displayProductName()`

Comment: could yo give me an example ? I'm really new on Dynamics and is a litle bit complicate for my understand how it works that but thank you for your time !!

Comment: @PaulNoris: Aliaksandr already added an example to his answer. If you are struggling with using a display method (which is a very basic thing in AX development), I strongly urge you to get some training.

Comment: I know, it's taking me a lot of time understand how Dynamics works, I have 1 month, and I don't know where study Dynamics, I can't understand the oficial documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/.. If you can give me a recomendation, I will be very grateful !